# passing folder path as argument from windows batch file to cygwin bash script

Tags: bash, shell, cygwin

I am trying to execute the following command in a shell script :

```
find "$1" -type f -name "*.DAT" -exec sed -e 's/.*/\"&\"/' {} ';' -exec xargs wc -l ';'
```

the command is supposed to run from a windows batch file as follows:

```
set arg1=%1
C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe row_count.sh %arg1%
```

Where row_count.sh is the shell script containing the find command above. The user is supposed to pass in a folder path to the batch file which is then supposed to pass on the folder path parameter to the find command in the shell script.

But I am getting following error:

```
FIND: Invalid Switch
```

please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FIND: Invalid Switch` is a error message from windows find not from cygwin one.

So you need to use a login shell to properly set the PATH

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe -l row_count.sh %arg1%
```

In addition be sure to put on the first row of `row_count.sh`
the `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: now it is saying /usr/bin/bash: row_count.sh: No such file or directory

Comment: row_count.sh and word_count.bat both are in C:\

Comment: Put those files in your Cygwin home directory.